# How to turn bytearray into IList in Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, arrays, ilist

How to turn Array (like Camera.names) into IList (for for ex MXML s:DropDownList

```
<s:DropDownList x="113" y="121" selectedIndex="0" dataProvider="{Camera.names}"></s:DropDownList>
```

)?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, as Array and ByteArray are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myList:IList = new ArrayCollection(sourceArray);
```